# Dados tipo Date

Tags: html, data

Tenho uma duvida e não sei se é possivel isso no Html. 
Dentro de um formulario tenho varios tipos de campos e um deles é o tipo DATE que recebe (Dia/mes/Ano) e agora queria alterar isso para receber apenas (mes/ano).

Consigo fazer essa alteração de forma simples?

Isso uso Jquery e Html

```
 <center> <b><h2> <p>Dados Estatisticos:</p> </b> </center>
<h3><center> 
    Data:
    <input type="date" name="EstatisticosValidade">
```

Comment: você está utilizando alguma máscara no campo? usa jquery? acrescente mais detalhes para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Consegue, sim. Mas pra gente poder ajudar, você precisa responder o comentário do Filipe.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize **month** no lugar de **date**. Talvez isso resolva o seu problema.

```
<input type="month" name="EstatisticosValidade">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar dois campos (type month e type number, com valor mínimo e máximo) ou separar por javascript ou php o valor inserido no campo com type date. Eu normalmente uso a segunda opção.